# Hibernate mapping for composite key

Tags: java, hibernate

I am trying to insert records to a table using hibernate. The table structure is like below

```
CREATE TABLE MYTABLE 
(   
    TRADE_ID NUMBER(18,0) NOT NULL, 
    EFFECTIVE_DATE DATE NOT NULL, 
    AMOUNT BINARY_DOUBLE NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    CREATED_TS TIMESTAMP (6), 
    UPDATED_TS TIMESTAMP (6), 
    CONSTRAINT MYTABLE_PK PRIMARY KEY ("TRADE_ID", "EFFECTIVE_DATE")
) ;
```

Could yo please help me with the mapping xml for the composite key ?

Comment: did you try my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this in your `mytable.hbm.xml` file.

```
  <composite-id name="id" class="MyCompositeKeyClass">
     <key-property name="tradeId" column="TRADE_ID" type="integer"/>
     <key-property name="effectiveDate" column="EFFECTIVE_DATE" type="date"/>
  </composite-id>
```

Then in your `MyCompositeKeyClass` class you can define the `tradeId` and `effectiveDate` fields.

```
public class MyCompositeKeyClass implements Serializable {
   private Integer tradeId;
   private Date effectiveDate;

   public MyCompositeKeyClass() {
   }
   // setters, getters
}
```

and in your `MyTable` class you should add a field

```
private MyCompositeKeyClass id;
```